# Manualy drawn bounding box is not draggable when using leaflet

Tags: javascript, leaflet, gis

The bounding box is created after you put in lat/lon and select draw.  After drawing bounding box, the custom box is not drag-able. If you select the drawing rectangle from the map's menu the bounding boxes are drag-able. How do I make the manually created bounding box drag-able?  Thanks in advance.
[Manually Created Bounding Box](https://jsfiddle.net/sv6wx0Ld/)

```
function drawRectangle()
{
var lat_lon_array = [];
var north = document.getElementById("north").value;
var west = document.getElementById("west").value;
var east = document.getElementById("east").value;
var south = document.getElementById("south").value;
var lat_lon = [[north,east],[south,west]];
var rectangle = L.rectangle(lat_lon);
rectangle.addTo(map);
map.fitBounds(rectangle.getBounds());
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
function drawRectangle()
{
var lat_lon_array = [];
var north = document.getElementById("north").value;
var west = document.getElementById("west").value;
var east = document.getElementById("east").value;
var south = document.getElementById("south").value;
var lat_lon = [[north,east],[south,west]];
// Pass it also the second argument (options) with 'draggable' marked as true
var rectangle = L.rectangle(lat_lon, { draggable: true });
rectangle.addTo(map);
map.fitBounds(rectangle.getBounds());
}
```